# What is the difference between `Ctrl b + d` and `Ctrl b + Ctrl z` in tmux?

Tags: shell, tmux

They do quit from tmux session equally.

I want to know the difference between `detach` and `hang on`.

Comment: `C-b C-c` is not a standard combination, at least I can't find it. Are you sure it's not defined in your configuration?

Comment: @KamilCuk `C-z` actually, sorry for that. And the question has been modified.

Answer (score 2):

`C-z` by itself would suspend the foreground program in the current pane, not the `tmux` client itself. So `<prefix> C-z` allows you to suspend the client. Once you are back in the shell from which you started the client, you can use `fg` to resume the client.

`<prefix> d`, on the other hand, detaches from the current session and *exits* the client.

Comment: And ... What's the difference between `suspend` and `exits` the client?

Comment: Like I said: `fg` will resume a suspended process. If the process *exits*, there's nothing to resume. "Suspended" means the process is alive, just not given any CPU time to proceed. Any in-memory state is preserved until it is resumed. (Though from your point of view, there's little practical difference between suspending and resuming the client, and killing and restarting a new client, since in both cases the actual session continues running in the background.)